# Session Mechanism not Working after upgrade to 4.1

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

We are working on one web app in which we are using AngularJS+Laravel 4. All works fine with AngularJS.

Now we have a requirement to use this same API for our Mobile Apps. So we are returning session id to mobile users after successful authentication. And they were sending this session id in header as cookie with **laravel_session** key when they are making any request. All were working fine in Laravel 4.

Now we have migrated our Laravel version to 4.1. So now its not working. I had checked it with previous version, in previous version of Laravel 4 it was returning session id in **laravel_session** cookie. But in new version (4.1) its returning some long string. I had seen release notes of 4.1. They told like they had rewritten Session engine.

I don't know how its generated and from where its settled. I had tried to get this value from Cookie by `Cookie::get('laravel_session')` after authentication. But it not worked. May be its settled while sending final response in cookie.

Anyone know how can I do that ?? Or any other alternative to handle this.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: When Laravel creates a session it adds a `Set-Cookie` header with that cookie. You app should just get that cookie and resend it with every request.

Answer (score 0):

We Solved this problem via reading the cookie value from Header stuff on our Mobile Apps.

Not they are getting this cookie value from header and sending it in every request they made.